# Behaviour of Threads during blocking IO in Java ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, thread-sleep, forkjoinpool

If the Thread inside the ForkJoinPool does a blocking I/O activity ( simulated below in code using `Thread.sleep(10000)`) , it should pick up another task which is not causing blocking IO.
However, running below code with parallelism of 1 or 2 with ForkJoinPool the results don't match it. The Thread doesn't relinquish the blocking task(i.e task 1 and task2 ) and moves to non blocking ( task 3 ).
In case of pool size =1 , all tasks execute in sequence whereas I expected Task 3 to complete first as it was non blocking in both cases ( pool size=1 or 2)

What is the actual behaviour of Threads in ForkJoinPool in case of blocking IO ?

```
    ForkJoinPool pool = new  ForkJoinPool(1);
    
    List<Future<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
    

    //Blocking
    tasks.add(pool.submit(() ->  {  Thread.sleep(10000); System.out.println("Task 1 woke up"+ Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()); return "task1"; }));
    //Blocking
    tasks.add(pool.submit(() ->  { Thread.sleep(10000); System.out.println("Task 2 woke up"+Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()); return "task2"; }));
    //Non Blocking
    tasks.add(pool.submit(() ->  {  System.out.println("Task 3 Runs"+Thread.currentThread().isDaemon()); return "task3"; }));
    

    
    int i=0;
    System.out.println("pool size = " + pool.getParallelism() + "Thread count=" +pool.getPoolSize() + "Stealing =" + pool.getStealCount());
    System.out.println("waiting");
    
    String str1 = tasks.get(0).get();
    String str2 = tasks.get(1).get();
    String str3 = tasks.get(2).get();
    
    System.out.println("Results = " +  str1+ str2 +str3);
    
    System.out.println("done");
```

Results :

> //Pool size = 2
> Task 2 woke uptrue
> Task 1 woke uptrue
> Task 3 Runstrue

> //Pool size = 1
> Task 1 woke uptrue
> Task 2 woke uptrue
> Task 3 Runstrue

Another observation:
When we submit Task 3( non blocking ) first then only it is invoked first.

Comment: What version of Java? It's like you expect fibers to be implemented?

Comment: Hi Nathan, Its Java 15. I expected threads in ForkJoinPool to switch to non blocking task when their current assigned task does some IO. As per Project Loom , ForkJoinPool will be used for Fibers so was expecting it to behave that way. https://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rpressler/loom/Loom-Proposal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForkJoinPool is used only as a scheduler as mentioned in the Loom Proposal. Only Virtual Threads have the ability to relinquish the blocking task and switch to another task. Based on what I remember from reading a mail in the loom mailing list,  the loom team is currently not planning to redesign java.util.concurrent's ForkJoinPool to use Virtual Threads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> If the Thread inside the ForkJoinPool does a blocking I/O activity ( simulated below in code using Thread.sleep(10000)) , it should pick up another task which is not causing blocking IO.

This is not how threads behave.  A thread represents an inflight execution.  It can't arbitrarily jump to another `Runnable`.  The thread has no way of knowing whether the thread is blocking for I/O or performing intense calculations, *unless* the threading engine AND the particular I/O is desgined for this (e.g. jdbc vs. r2dbc).

In other words if you use Reactor/Spring Reactive/some other reactive programming framework with a traditional blocking I/O, like JDBC, your threads will still hang up waiting for I/O.

Blocking I/O is often implemented as a loop while polling a socket, there is no way for anything outside the particular I/O to know that this is in fact blocking I/O.

To my knowledge the `ForkJoinPool` is not reactive, it hands Runnables to threads, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The `ForkJoinPool` cannot arbitrarily detect situations where it should start other tasks to maintain the parallelism and where not.

So are work item that is waiting for something has to explicitly tell the `ForkJoinPool` that it should start other tasks to maintain the parallelism.

To achieve this you have to use `ForkJoinPool#managedBlock` or any API that uses it underneath.

If you for example use `CompletableFuture#join` or `CompletableFuture#get`, then these methods under the hood use `ForkJoinPool#managedBlock` and thus would allow the `ForkJoinPool` to start other tasks to maintain intended parallelism.

A simple `Thread.sleep` is not working for this.

If you replace in your example the `Thread.sleep(10000);` by `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (Exception e) {}; }).join();`, then you get exactly the behavior you intended.